# using move semantics to initialize class member in constructor

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, move-semantics, move-constructor

I'm studying multithreading in C++ and I wrote a simple class that contains a private `std::mutex` object to synchronize on when a member funcrion is called:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

class SynchClass
{
public:
    SynchClass() {}
    void inline SynchronizedInterfaceFunction();    
private:
    std::mutex mMutex;
};

void inline SynchClass::SynchronizedInterfaceFunction()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mMutex);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        std::cout << "thread n: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " inside function" << std::endl; 

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Now, I this function has a `delete`d copy constructor and copy assignment operator, since std::mutex can be moved but not copyed/assigned.

So I provide the class with a move constructor (which is not automatically generated by compiler):

```
class SynchClass
    {
    public:
        // ... other members as before
        SynchClass(SynchClass &&rhs) : mMutex(std::move(rhs.mMutex)) {}

    };
```

but when I ad this line the compiler complains that I'm trying to call the deleted copy constructor of `std::mutex`:

```
In file included from main.cpp:5:0:
SynchClass.h: In constructor 'SynchClass::SynchClass(SynchClass&&)':
SynchClass.h:8:61: error: use of deleted function 'std::mutex::mutex(const std::mutex&)'
  SynchClass(SynchClass &&rhs) : mMutex(std::move(rhs.mMutex)) {}
                                                             ^
In file included from C:/Program Files/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/include/c++/mutex:43:0,
                 from main.cpp:2:
C:/Program Files/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.2.0/include/c++/bits/std_mutex.h:97:5: note: declared here
     mutex(const mutex&) = delete;
```

but I'm using `std::move` to cast the lvalue to an rvalue, so the move constructor of std::mutex should be called.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::mutex` is not copyable and not movable. It does not have move constructor or assignment. Library requirements for `mutex`:

> **33.4.3.2 Mutex types [thread.mutex.requirements.mutex]**
>   3
>   The mutex types shall be DefaultConstructible and Destructible . If initialization of an object of a
>   mutex type fails, an exception of type system_error shall be thrown. The mutex types shall not be copyable
>   or movable.

If you want to make your class move constructible then you will need to add another layer of indirection at some point, for example by using `std::unique_ptr<std::mutex>`.